# Could not run Android emulator as could not initialize emulated framebufferHAX in Windows 7

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Google map activity and added some dependencies to display the map on an emulator.

I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_One_API_21
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software     renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: device fd:524
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
Could not initialize emulated framebufferHAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
ERROR: Could not create renderer: Couldn't find matching render driver
```

I reinstalled all plugins and SDK but it didn't help.

The emulator is shown for a millisecond and disappears again, and I end up with this message.

Comment: i recommend you to use genymotion emulator, https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because of video drivers not working properly or its not compatible with the emulator screen display resolution.

So just update your windows driver and restart the system, keeping your display or screen at highest resolution, then start your Android Studio and it will work fine. Just Google how to update your video driver or display driver and you can go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

GenyMotion or Andy or BlueStacks does require VT-x support as well. Try an older API SDK for slow emulator..:-(

Answer (score 0):

When you're working on a Remote Desktop, disconnecting and connecting again to the host machine can help.