# Facing Error While Running Android Application in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I use a android studio and when i run my application i got this **error**

> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay
>   none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86
>       Failed to create Context 0x3005
>       could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>       could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>       emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
>       could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>       could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>       could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>       could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>       could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>       could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>       emulator: device fd:548
>       Could not initialize emulated framebufferHAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
>       emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
>       emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
>       emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869640/could-not-run-android-emulator-as-could-not-initialize-emulated-framebufferhax-i)

Comment: Jaipal, since you are on windows..it appears to be video driver problem..

this error line:

emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.

Comment: I have already allocate 1 Gb memory (Ram) To my elmulator