# emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running the same code from https://github.com/google/gcm with no customization yet. I used Android Studio 1.2.2 and JDK 1.8 and imported the project and when I run it wait for 5 mins then I see the following error.

I did search the web and I find very similar error but not exact on the [Could not run Android emulator as could not initialize emulated framebufferHAX in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869640/could-not-run-android-emulator-as-could-not-initialize-emulated-framebufferhax-i).

The error snippet for reference

```
C:\....\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
Creating filesystem with parameters:
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Blocks per group: 32768
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Inodes per group: 4224
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Label: 
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
    Reserved block group size: 7
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

Comment: did you try to use `-gpu off`?

Comment: I got this error with other errors Android Studio 3 and Win 10. I could resolve it by installing everything.

Comment: What do you mean "installing everything"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while Running Android Application - Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio, the GPU can be disabled from the advanced settings from the AVD Manager.[image]

Hoping this will help.

Comment: Way way too slow. This is not an acceptable option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to AVD Manager.
Edit your AVD.
Select 'Software GLES2.0' option on Emulated Performance. (The reason is because some users did not install graphic video card drivers )
Click Finish (Save).
Start AVD again.

Comment: Way way too slow. This is not an acceptable option.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to device resolution incompatibility.
Try reducing the avd resoultion to 1280X720 or lower

Comment: Try adding some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have GPU or Graphics card in your system Follow below steps :

Just edit the emulator configurations ->
click on Show Advanced Setting
Select Graphics : Software- GLES 2.0

just save the changes and restart AVD.

Answer (score -1):

on windows systems:

edit config file for virtual device

e.g.: C:\Users.android\avd\Nexus_7_API_17.avd\config.ini

> ... hw.gpu.enabled=no ...